# Camel Wire Tap - Use to accept two inputs

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

In my camel project I have a route going from a file input folder to a file output folder. I also have an activemq route going from file input folder to certain queues.

My concern is how do I use the wire tap method to allow for both input from my file input folder and from activemq in my route?

My task is to make whatever activemq sends go into the file output folder and whatever the file input folder gets go into a queue.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like multicast vs wiretap (at times they can look similar)

1. Read from the file
2. Send to two endpoints (output folder and a queue)

   ```
   <from uri="file:inputFolder"/>
   <multicast stopOnException="true">
       <to uri="file:outputFolder"/>
       <to uri="amq:queue:OUTPUT_QUEUE"/>
   </multicast>
   ```

Note: Multicast is good for when you want to link the two "to" steps together for error handling, or alternatively to run both steps in parallel.

You could just as easily do this with from().to().to() since all steps are InOnly:

```
   <from uri="file:inputFolder"/>
   <to uri="file:outputFolder"/>
   <to uri="amq:queue:OUTPUT_QUEUE"/>
```